# Border Radius Doesn't work in ios4?

Tags: ios, css, ios4

I'm using border-radius:50%;

This doesn't work in IOS4?

but http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius says it does?

Huh? Whats going on?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MnquK/ Demo of it working, view in IOS4 and it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IOS4,

It appears that it doesn't support border-radius:50%?

Therefore had to come up with some JS to work out the percentage in Pixels.

Something Like:

```
var radius = circleWidth / 2;
$jq('.circle').css('border-radius', radius + "px")
```

Doesn't appear to be documented anywhere either.

Answer (score 0):

According to [css3.info](http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/): percentages refer to the corresponding dimensions of the border box.
Does you box have a defined height/width?

Comment: width is set by the stylesheet then its height is set by javascript, I'm creating a css circle. Fiddle for basic html: http://jsfiddle.net/MnquK/ and still doesn't work?

Comment: Alright, but if your `height` and `width` are `100px`, then why not just use `50px` for the `border-radius`?

Comment: Hi Jason, the width of the elements was fluid and therefore could not do this with 50px.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work on other mobile browsers?

Maybe you need to add the -webkit- prefix to it.

Comment: I have prefixed it with the vendor webkit and it still doesnt work? appears that it only works if its in pixels measurement?